# Mac App mysteriously disappears directly after downloading and installing from the Mac AppStore

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, osx-lion, mac-app-store

Last night we have released a free app in the Mac AppStore. The app didn't yet show up when searching for (parts of) the title, however, we could find it by searching for one of our existing Mac Apps and clicking through to our 'Developer Page'.

When 'buying' the app (it's actually free), the icon pops up in LaunchPad and the progress bar for downloading & installing shows. Under Snow Leopard, the icon pops into the Dock and the progress bar for downloading & installing shows.

However, in both cases, as soon as the progress bar is filled, the app directly disappears from the LaunchPad / Dock and can no longer be started.

I've checked my Applications folder, but the app is nowhere to be found. I also checked this on other systems (under user accounts that never develop in XCode), those showed the exact same problem. I've also tried downloading a few other free apps from the Mac AppStore on my own system, these downloaded and installed successfully and don't disappear.

There seems to be a problem with our app that causes this issue, but I have no idea what it could possibly be. I didn't find anyone else suffering from this problem.

First and foremost, I would love to know what causes this so we can fix it.

Secondly, I am wondering how this app ever came through Apple's review process having this issue.

Any ideas?? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you see if you use Terminal and "ls" the directory that the app should be in? Both while downloading and post-completion. Also, you might be able to use "sudo fs_usage" to see exact specifics of what's happening.

Comment: The app really isn't there; it doesn't show up using "ls". 
I used sudo fs_usage; in order to lessen its output I quit all my applications and tried the download again.. it worked properly this time :S. Then I ran to a Snow Leopard machine, which still showed the same issue. There, I saw fs_usage unlinking a whole load of our game's resources after installation. Strangely, it deleted files from another user's folder, instead of the global Applications folder that's meant to hold the app. So I'm currently guessing that the issue is related to downloading the app on a machine its built on..?

Comment: Maybe it's trying to remove old versions and only keep the newest version? BTW, if you make the window wide enough, fs_usage should show which app is making the changes.

Comment: Yes, your fs_usage tip confirmed the reply on Apple Developer Forums with regard to an old debug build being overwritten, therefore directly hiding the newly installed version from LaunchPad, the Dock and the Applications Folder. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An Apple Dev on the Apple Developer Forums answered this question:

> Do you have a copy of that app elsewhere on the system? App Store will install it over an existing copy, whereever that copy happens to be.

A different user on my system had previously built a debug build of the app from XCode. Apparently, any downloaded versions of Mac Apps are written over those apps -- even if the old version is within the home folder of a different user on your system, any version you purchase/download from the Mac AppStore will overwrite thát version; effectively locking out the downloading user from the app that he may have just paid for.

Imho, that's a crappy way of handling 'updates'. But it's good to know our app is working fine.

Thanks for the help StilesCrisis!

**Update:** Apple has asked me to file a bug report for this issue, will do.

Comment: Thank you so much! In fact, I had to delete trial versions of the app that were stored in the Downloads folder.

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing an app on Electron, and for me problem was that I had build files in my project folder, even after I deleted the app which I installed with `.dmg` in Application folder. So, it seems Mac Store looks throw whole disk space and trying to find app with same app ID, and if it exists, don't rewrite it.

After deleting my `.app` and `.pkg` build from the project folder app successfully installed from Mac Store. If it will not work for you, please try to clean app related folder in these directions: `~/Library/Caches` and `/Library/Application Support`. I did it before, and can't guarantee that removing only project build files can help you. Maybe these actions are somehow connected. And removing app build files do not work for you.